# QTreeView Data Changed Signal/Slot Implementation?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.7, qtreeview

I am using pyqt5 / python 3.7 / win10 and I have a QTreeView that has only one editable column which can be edited just fine.  What I need to do now is tell the the program that the field has been changed (or to check if it has) either when a return or enter are pressed or the field loses focus due to a mouse click anywhere else.

I have included a simple program that reflects my full situation thus far with all its layers and we have opted for a single click instead of the double click for selecting the field to edit.

I have spent quite a bit of time trying to figure this one out and while I have seen possible answers I have yet to get one to work for me.  I am sure it is probably rather straight-forward but I am having a dickens of a time implementing the solution.

```py
from sys import exit as sysExit

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui  import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class CustomItemModel(QStandardItemModel):
    def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
        if role == Qt.ForegroundRole:
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(Qt.blue)
            brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
            return brush

        elif role == Qt.BackgroundRole:
            brush = QBrush()
            brush.setColor(Qt.yellow)
            brush.setStyle(Qt.SolidPattern)
            return brush

        elif role == Qt.FontRole:
            font = QFont()
            font.setBold(True)
            font.setPointSize(10)
            return font

        return super().headerData(section, orientation, role)

class ItemDsplyr(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, CentrPane):
        QTreeView.__init__(self, CentrPane)
        self.CntrPane = CentrPane
        self.setEditTriggers(QTreeView().NoEditTriggers)
        self.model = CustomItemModel(0, 4)

        self.model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(['', 'ItemName', 'Value', 'Units'])
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
        self.setModel(self.model)

        self.setColumnWidth(0, 1)  #Not sure what the minimum column width is but is greater than 1
        self.setColumnHidden(0, True)

        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.Fixed)

        self.header().setStretchLastSection(False)
        self.header().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        self.setColumnWidth(2, 75)
        self.setColumnWidth(3, 100)

        self.clicked.connect(self.__itemSingleClicked)

    @property
    def CntrPane(self):
        return self.__parent

    @CntrPane.setter
    def CntrPane(self, value):
        self.__parent = value

    def SetContent(self, tmpItmList):
        self.model.setRowCount(0)

        for Item in tmpItmList:
            blnkVal = QStandardItem('')

            ItmNam = QStandardItem(Item['ItemName'])
            ItmNam.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            ItmNam.isEditable = False

            ItmVal = QStandardItem(Item['Value'])
            ItmVal.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

            ItmUnt = QStandardItem((Item['Units']))
            ItmUnt.setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignLeft)
            ItmUnt.isEditable = False

            self.model.appendRow([blnkVal, ItmNam, ItmVal, ItmUnt])

    def __itemSingleClicked(self, index):
        Item = self.selectedIndexes()[0]
        CurRow = index.row()
        ItemIdx = index.sibling(CurRow, 1)
        ValuIdx = index.sibling(CurRow, 2)
        self.edit(ValuIdx)

        ItemVal = Item.model().itemFromIndex(ItemIdx).text()
        ValuVal = Item.model().itemFromIndex(ValuIdx).text()
        self.CntrPane.CurItemValue(ItemVal, ValuVal)

class CenterPanel(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, MainWin):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        self.MainWin = MainWin
        self.ListItm = ''
        self.ListVal = ''

        ItmList = [
            {'ItemName':'Cal-Itm-1', 'Value':'54',  'Units':'Units'},
            {'ItemName':'Cal-Itm-2', 'Value':'54',  'Units':'Units'},
            {'ItemName':'Cal-Itm-1', 'Value':'10',  'Units':'Passes'},
            {'ItemName':'Cal-Itm-2', 'Value':'2.5', 'Units':'Volts'},
            {'ItemName':'Run-Itm-1', 'Value':'2',   'Units':'Units'},
            {'ItemName':'Run-Itm-2', 'Value':'1',   'Units':'Units'},
            {'ItemName':'Run-Itm-1', 'Value':'10',  'Units':'Units'},
            {'ItemName':'Run-Itm-2', 'Value':'50',  'Units':'Units'},
            {'ItemName':'Tbl-Itm-1', 'Value':'0',   'Units':'Units'},
            {'ItemName':'Tbl-Itm-2', 'Value':'0',   'Units':'Units'},
            {'ItemName':'Tbl-Itm-1', 'Value':'0',   'Units':'Units'},
            {'ItemName':'Tbl-Itm-2', 'Value':'255', 'Units':'Units'}
            ]

        self.CatGrpTree = QTextEdit()

        self.ItemDsply = ItemDsplyr(self)
        self.ItemDsply.SetContent(ItmList)

        CntrPane = QSplitter(Qt.Horizontal, self)
        CntrPane.addWidget(self.CatGrpTree)
        CntrPane.addWidget(self.ItemDsply)
        CntrPane.setSizes([50,200])

        hbox = QHBoxLayout(self)
        hbox.addWidget(CntrPane)

        self.setLayout(hbox)

    @property
    def MainWin(self):
        return self.__parent

    @MainWin.setter
    def MainWin(self, value):
        self.__parent = value

    def CurItemValue(self, LstItm, LstVal):
        print("List Item/Value Clicked:",LstItm,"/",LstVal)
        if LstItm != self.ListItm:
            self.ListItm = LstItm
            self.ListVal = LstVal

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)

        self.title = 'Main Window'
        self.left = 100
        self.ztop = 100
        self.wide = 700
        self.high = 600

        self.InitGUI()

    def InitGUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.ztop, self.wide, self.high)

        self.CenterPane = CenterPanel(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.CenterPane)

        self.setStyle(QStyleFactory.create('Cleanlooks'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp = QApplication([])
    # This fixes a display issue with Windows
    MainApp.setStyle("fusion")

    MainGUI = Window()
    MainGUI.show()

    sysExit(MainApp.exec_())
```

As can be seen (upon running this) you get a QTreeView (mostly just a List but from my research the QTreeView was best to use). If you click a row you are immediately placed in an edit mode in the Value column. However I cannot determine how to know when to check if the field has changed (I am capturing the values pre-edit). So an On-Lost-Focus would be sufficient but a Data-Changed would be better.

Comment: No the QTreeView does not close but if you click elsewhere the current row-column value loses focus or if you press enter/return the current row-column value loses focus.  So when the that specific row-column value of the QTreeView, which has been selected, loses focus I want to know this and/or mostly just if the data was changed upon losing focus

Comment: Actually I was not using an additional editor object (or were you meaning this as well) I was simply using the edit capability of the QTreeView on the specified row-column based on the selection.

Comment: Okay did not quite understand that.  Are you saying that when I invoke the edit() function upon the row-column that it creates a spinbox (whatever that is?) otherwise what happens can be seen by running the program -- its simply an in-line edit of the 2nd visual column in the row selected and I do not know enough about pyqt5 to tell what it implements to do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194960/discussion-between-dennis-jensen-and-eyllanesc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to get the text of the item if it was only changed then you must use the [`dataChanged(...)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#dataChanged) signal

```py
# ...
class ItemDsplyr(QTreeView):
    def __init__(self, CentrPane):
        QTreeView.__init__(self, CentrPane)
        # ...
        self.model.setHeaderData(2, Qt.Horizontal, Qt.AlignCenter, Qt.TextAlignmentRole)
        self.model.dataChanged.connect(self.on_data_changed)
        # ...

    @pyqtSlot("QModelIndex", "QModelIndex", "QVector<int>")
    def on_data_changed(self, top_left, bottom_right, roles):
        if top_left == bottom_right and Qt.DisplayRole in roles:
            print(top_left.data())
# ...
```

Comment: I knew it was something fairly straightforward thanks a lot

Comment: P.S. I am curious because I just stumbled across this after I finally posted my question and while this works I am wondering should I have used QDelegate with this instead and/or does QDelegate handle and field edit -- everything I have seen folks pop-up and editing mini-window